# Indications that a Neural Network would benefit from a deeper architecture

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Are there any generally accepted indications based upon bias, variance, accuracy, loss, or another feature that indicate that a Neural Network architecture would benefit from having a deeper structure (other than explicit testing of the deeper architecture)?

I know that a deeper architecture does not always translate into performance increases and can sometimes make performance worse, and I am working on a large Network and dataset, so was trying to analyze current NN signals to determine if a deeper network architecture would be beneficial before explicitly testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic got much attention in the last few years, yet I don't know of any important proof in the field that says that deeper architectures are better than shallower ones for a given problem.

Some works like [this one](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v49/cohen16.html) show that certain deep networks learn functions that a shallow network (with only one hidden layer) would have to be exponentially large to learn them. Note that it is not the same as what you are looking for.

The architectures that are considered state-of-the-art today are usually built with empirical trial-and-error combined with some insights from past successes.

Comment: @David Ariel, Gonna accept this answer, I think it is the best that is probably available at this time in NN research. Maybe one day, one of use will come up with a better answer!